# PHP Form sending value from an id instead of value

Tags: php, forms, dom, request

What I have typically been doing is something like this in a form with a hidden field:

```
   <input type="hidden" name="someName" value="someVal" />
```

and I have been able to get the value with something simple like

```
$someVar = $_REQUEST['someVal'];
```

But now  I am trying to send all the values in a DOM element id by something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="someNewName" id="element_id_name" />
```

I am doing this correctly?  Can this even be done?  Or am I way off?
How do I get the value out of the last line?  Or how do I send that data to to request in a correct way?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cant not retrieve data in php via ID it works on name..so you neeed to change

#### PHP

```
<form method="POST" action="nextpage.php" name="myform" id="myform">
<input type="text" id="rout_markers"  name="rout_markers"/>
<input type="hidden" name="someNewName" id="someNewName" value="" />
<input type="submit" id="send-btn"  class="button" value="SEND NOW" onclick="submitform()" />
</form>
```

#### jQuery

```
$("form").bind('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var hiddenData=$("input[name=rout_markers]").val();
  // or var hiddenData=jQuery('#rout_markers').val(); 
  $("input[type=hidden][name=someNewName]").val(hiddenData);  
});
```

on

#### nextpage.php

retrieve data below way

> $_POST['someNewName'];

#### update

set `onclick=submitform()` in submit button and also assign `name` and `id` attribute to form and write this

### javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitform()
{
  var hiddenData = document.getElementById('rout_markers').value;
  document.getElementById('someNewName').value = hiddenData;
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: That didn't work.  How do I send the value of everything in that element id via value="element_id_name" ? as it is now, even when that element is populated, the REQUEST just gets an empty value sent to it.

Comment: what exactly u want to send? using POST or GET??

Comment: Hi, did you mean something somewhat like this?  If so, how can I make the following work -->   <input type="hidden" name="markers" id="rout_markers" value="<script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementById('rout_markers').value; </script>" />
- thanks!! :)

Comment: Thank you - but what if I am not using jquery.  How do I handle this in simple JavaScript? - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can only receive inputs with a `name` attribute, which becomes the key of your `$_POST` (or equivalent) array.

Please use `$_POST` (or `$_GET`) instead of `$_REQUEST`, the latter also looks at cookies, and one could clobber what you expect. You should follow [Principle of Least Privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

To send that one with an `id` to your server, give it a unique name or send the `value` property to your server via XHR.

Comment: By the way, do you think that something like this would work:    <input type="hidden" name="markers" id="rout_markers" value="<script type='text/javascript'> document.getElementById('rout_markers').value; </script>" />

Comment: And yes, you are right about using the get/post requests.  I am just using the REQUEST for easier testing.

Comment: By XHR - do you mean XMLHTTPRequest?  If so, how would I do that?  Would it be still via that same kind of form thing?  Or something much more complicated? - thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like DOM in HTTP protocol.

If you want to send an HTML form via HTTP request, you have to use `value` attribute, that's all

Comment: But then what would be the best way to send those values in the submission of the form? I am just curious if there are good options.

Comment: @Genadinik what about just usual options? Just set them and let it be sent?

Comment: Problem is that the values are set with some google maps javascript, and I am not sure how to put the values into the form :-/

Answer (score -1):

In the first case, you have to get the value of the field in php using:

```
$someVar = $_REQUEST['someName'];
```

For the second case, you can get value in php using:

```
$someNewVar = $_REQUEST['someNewName'];
```

and in javascript, you can get its value like:

```
var somenewvar = document.getElementById("element_id_name").value;
```