# How to POST HTML form using `id` instead of `name`

Tags: javascript, php, element

This following code will get element by name, I'm gonna change it to get element by ID, how to make it?

```
<?
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && array_key_exists("calculateFormSubmit", $_POST)) {
    $connectionData = ["server" => "","user" => "","pass" => "","database" => ""];
    $db = null;
    try {
      $db = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $connectionData["server"] . ";dbname=" . $connectionData["database"], $connectionData["user"], $connectionData["pass"]);
      $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $dateFrom = (int)$_POST["YearBox"] . "-" . (int)$_POST["gmonth"] . "-" . (int)$_POST["gday1"];
    $dateTo = (int)$_POST["gyear2"] . "-" . (int)$_POST["gmonth2"] . "-" . (int)$_POST["gday2"];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(rialamount) as sum_result FROM problem_tbl WHERE opening_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(:date_from, '%Y-%c-%e') AND STR_TO_DATE(:date_to, '%Y-%c-%e')");

    $stmt->bindValue(":date_from", $dateFrom);
    $stmt->bindValue(":date_to", $dateTo);
    $stmt->execute();
    $userData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($userData != false) {
    foreach ($userData as $idPatient) {
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
            echo "<p>Text Here </p>\n";
            echo "<div id=\"rialamount\" style=\"text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #0B4D09; font-size: 140%;\">\n";
            echo       "<b>" .  ['']  .        "<b> - "  . $idPatient["sum_result"] . "<br />";
            echo "</div>\n";
    }
    }

    if($db !== null) {
        $db = null;
    }
}
?>
```

In the **$dateFrom** and **$dateTo** will get element by class name, How to change them to get element by ID ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Form sending value from an id instead of value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440823/php-form-sending-value-from-an-id-instead-of-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cant not retrieve data in php via ID it works on name..so you neeed to change

**PHP**

```
<form method="POST" action="nextpage.php" name="myform" id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="rout_markers"  name="rout_markers"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="someNewName" id="someNewName" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="send-btn"  class="button" value="SEND NOW" onclick="submitform()" />
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("form").bind('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var hiddenData=$("input[name=rout_markers]").val();
  // or var hiddenData=jQuery('#rout_markers').val(); 
  $("input[type=hidden][name=someNewName]").val(hiddenData);  
});
```

**nextpage.php**

retrieve data below way

```
$_POST['someNewName'];
```

**update**

Set `onclick=submitform()` in submit button and also assign `name` and `id` attribute to form and write this

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitform()
    {
        var hiddenData = document.getElementById('rout_markers').value;
        document.getElementById('someNewName').value = hiddenData;
        document.myform.submit();
    }
</script>
```

For more info, click [getting values from ID instead of name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440823/php-form-sending-value-from-an-id-instead-of-value/5440897#5440897)

Comment: Thanks, finally you showed me a way to solve it. Thanks bro

Comment: Always welcome Mr @AlexanderRichard. We all are here to help as much as we can. Glad to help. As it is not exact solution, but a path. Enjoy Coding. Happy Diwali From India.

Answer (score 1):

By default, an HTML `form` submits values keyed on the `name` attribute of the element.

You can modify this behavior using JavaScript by writing a function that handles the `onsubmit` action of the form and performing the submit yourself.

1. When the user hits `<input type="submit">` or otherwise submits the form, the [`submit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) event is triggered
2. If you have a JavaScript function set to handle `onsubmit`, it will be called at this point
3. Your function should then create an HTTP POST request to the desired server resource (i.e. the one specified in the `action` attribute of the form and containing the code in the question).  The POST data sent with this request can be keyed on ids or any other identifier you wish to use.
4. Your function should then cancel the form submit that would otherwise be initiated by the browser (e.g. `return false`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this,i've read somewhere that we can control element by only their name after HTML 4.01.

here, previous post also support it.
[previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351204/php-post-and-id-only-no-name)

But if , you really want to access it through id, then you have to use ajax call for sending data to server. In ajax call, you can access element by their Id.